# Select2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am attempting to upgrade from Select2 Version 4.0.7 to 4.0.13 (or anything in between). When I do I get the following error when clicking on a select box.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at r.option (select2.min.js:formatted:489)
    at r.append (select2.min.js:formatted:425)
    at d.<anonymous> (select2.min.js:formatted:530)
    at d.e.invoke (select2.min.js:formatted:289)
    at d.e.trigger (select2.min.js:formatted:283)
    at d.trigger (select2.min.js:formatted:3436)
    at select2.min.js:formatted:3353
    at n.query (select2.min.js:formatted:2138)
    at d.<anonymous> (select2.min.js:formatted:3352)
    at d.e.invoke (select2.min.js:formatted:289)
```

When I change back to version 4.0.7 everything goes back to working as expected. This happens on all of the select2 boxes on the site regardless of the options it is initialized with. I have tried both the full version and the regular versions.

I am using jQuery version 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

After further inspection there was some code in the project that was overwriting Window.Element. I fixed that code and the below polyfill is no longer needed.

**Original Answer**:

I'm not sure why but I discovered that I needed to add a polyfill in order to make it work. I am using Chrome Version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (64-bit) but for some reason Element.prototype.matches was returning undefined. I added the following [Polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to fix the issue:

```js
    //Select2 JS Polyfill
    if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
        Element.prototype.matches =
            Element.prototype.matchesSelector ||
            Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
            Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
            Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector ||
            Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
            function (s) {
                var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
                    i = matches.length;
                while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) { }
                return i > -1;
            };
    }
```